# Statuses (Social Microblog) module integration with organic group?

Tags: organic-groups

Looking for an integration with [Statuses (Social Microblog)](https://www.drupal.org/project/statuses) module and [Organic Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/og) module. Please share some keys if any one experience with it.

Comment: What kind of integration?

Comment: yes i got the solution! Thanks for the time to review.

Comment: OK, thanks. Assuming you are aware of http://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer, would you mind "documenting" your own question, in the format of an "answer"?